# Dart regular expression using `$1`

Tags: dart

I want to use `$1` in a`dart` regular expression to get the grouping in the expression.

Just like `javascript` regular expressions.

```
void main() {
  // javascript
  // 'hello-world'.replace(/-(w)/, '+$1'); // hello+world

  print('hello-world'.replaceAll(RegExp(r'-(w)'), '+\$1')); // hello+$1orld
}
```

Completely unexpected.

Expected result `hello+world`, actual result`hello+$1orld`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dart [`replaceAll` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) does not treat its second argument as a replacement pattern.

Rather than introduce a new language for specifying replacements in a string, Dart allows you to use a normal Dart expression to compute the replacement.
Dart has a short syntax for functions, so this is not much longer than the string, but it allows you to insert arbitrarily complicated computations when necessary.

So, use the [`replaceAllMapped`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html) function and write the replacement as follows:

```dart
print('hello-world'.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'-(w)'), (m) => '+${m[1]}'));
```

For this particular example, the RegExp is so simple that you can replace with a plain string:

```dart
print('hello-world'.replaceAll(RegExp(r'-(?=w)'), '+'));
```

This replaces a `-` with a `+` only when the `-` is followed by a `w`.